# What happens to Executing Procedure if I Recompile Package Body on a different Procedure in the Same Package

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

If I have 1 Package with 2 procedures (A & B) what would happen to package A if it was executing and I needed to edit procedure B and recompile the overall package body.

Would A error due to the recompiling of the package or would it still fire off?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You cannot compile package or package body if the procedure `A` is working because you will get `acquire nowait timeout` until `A` finishes.

Answer (score 1):

If the procedure is being executed, compilation will fail (actually, it'll wait until the package is *released*, i.e. nobody uses it).